# Matching a string with whitespace character in bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, bash, zsh, terminator

Basically, my goal is to print the rails version as a prompt segment to the terminator(terminal) as we enter a ROR project.

I have figured out a way how to display it as a custom segment in the terminator but I am having difficulty extracting the rails version. And to extract the rails version of a ROR project, there's a file called `Gemfile.lock` which has a list of ruby gems and the exact rails version it has installed for the app.

This is what a `Gemfile.lock` looks like:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      activejob (= 7.0.3.1)
      activerecord (= 7.0.3.1)
      activestorage (= 7.0.3.1)
      activesupport (= 7.0.3.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      ....
      ....
      rails (7.0.3.1)
      actioncable (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionpack (= 7.0.3.1)
      actiontext (= 7.0.3.1)
      actionview (= 7.0.3.1)
      activejob (= 7.0.3.1)
      activemodel (= 7.0.3.1)
     ....
     ....
DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap
  capybara
  debug
  importmap-rails
  jbuilder
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rails (~> 7.0.3, >= 7.0.3.1)
  redis (~> 4.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  ....
  ....
```

The gem I want to extract is     `rails (7.0.3.1)`

I am working on a `.zshrc` file to extract it and so far I have come up with this solution:

```bash
ver=`awk -F' ' '$1~/^rails/{print $0}' Gemfile.lock`
```

which gives the following output

```
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    rails (7.0.3.1)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
  rails (~> 7.0.3, >= 7.0.3.1)
```

As you can see there are multiple gems that include the name `rails` in them. But I only want to extract the version of this gem     `rails (7.0.3.1)` which has a leading 4 space characters in it.

The expected output I am looking for is just the version of the gem like this: `7.0.3.1` without parenthesis and return as a string type. This will then be stored in a variable and then I will print it out in the terminal as a custom prompt segment with a custom color like:

```
local color="%F{#f7507b}"
# ver = ``
echo "%{$color%}$ver"
```

where `ver` is the variable that has rails version stored in it.

I have been trying for the past half day but no luck and I have also tried using `[[:blank:]]` & `\s` but it doesn't work for this context. I have also tried using `rails -v` where it outputs the rails version of the project directory we are in, but this will also give an error in rare cases where the user doesn't have installed the ruby version specified in the `Gemfile`.

The output should give the version of rails the app uses regardless of whether the user has installed the particular version of ruby or rails in their system. So I think extracting the rails version from `Gemfile.lock` is the only way. But if you have any other approach towards this solution, I am all ears!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking exactly: The title of the question refers to bash, the body of the question refers to .zshrc, i.e. to zsh, and you are tagging it with both bash and zsh. Please make up your mind first, what shell you want to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu awk` you might use for example a pattern with a capture group.

The pattern matches:

- `^[[:space:]]*` Match optional spaces from the start of the string
- `rails[[:space:]]+` match `rails` and 1+ spaces
- `\(` match `(`
- `([0-9][0-9.]*)` Capture in group 1 matching a digit and optional dots and digits
- `\)` Match `)`

Example:

```
gawk 'match($0, /^[[:space:]]*rails[[:space:]]+\(([0-9][0-9.]*)\)/, a) {
  print a[1]
}' Gemfile.lock
```

Output

```
7.0.3.1
```

---

Or with `awk` and [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
awk '$1 == "rails" && match($2, /\([0-9][0-9.]*\)/) {
   print substr($2, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
}' Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks a ton! Works perfectly! Since I am new to bash, some of it seems gibberish like I can't understand this regexp: +\(([0-9][0-9.]*)\)/

Comment: @JuzerShakir I have added an explanation about the pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it thoroughly. :) I wish I had enough reputation to thumbs up ur answer however I have approved your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Updated to extract just the version number - `7.0.3.1` - and store in a variable:

```
$ awk '$1=="rails" {gsub(/[()]/,"",$2); print $2}' Gemfile.lock
7.0.3.1

$ ver=$(awk '$1=="rails" {gsub(/[()]/,"",$2); print $2}' Gemfile.lock)
$ typeset -p ver
declare -- ver="7.0.3.1"
```

---

Couple issues with the current code:

- `-F' '` - not necessary since the default field delimiter is white space, ie, (multiple) spaces and tabs
- since the desired line consists of the string `rails` with white space on each side we can simply use an equality comparison

A few `awk` ideas:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == "rails") print $0}' Gemfile.lock
awk '$1 == "rails" { print $0 }' Gemfile.lock
awk '$1 == "rails" { print }' Gemfile.lock
awk '$1=="rails"' Gemfile.lock
```

All of these generate:

```
      rails (7.0.3.1)
```

Comment: The updated solution works for extracting all the gems named 'rails' but there are 2 gems with the same name as you can see in the question. And it would be really helpful if you could explain the steps for the result achieved.

Comment: while the output from your `awk` code shows 2 gems named `rails`, the sample input file only contains a single gem named `rails`, and since I only have this sample input to work with ... the code 'works' as suggested; consider updating the question with a more representative set of data (eg, includes multiple gems named `rails`) ***AND*** include a description of how you determine which gem (named `rails`) to extract

Comment: Initially, I didn't explain it properly and I am sorry for that. But I have updated my query. The content of Gemfile.lock I gave already has those strings as 'rails' but only one of it is a gem. I know it, you know it but the program doesn't know and hence we need to extract that specific version of rails. Anyways, Thanks a lot :).

Comment: your sample input file does ***not*** show multiple gems as you've stated; you're assuming everyone who looks at your question has a working knowledge of ruby/gems and can ascertain (guess) at what your input file looks like; you increase your chances of getting a working answer(s) when you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: My sample output does show what I am talking about! Check this section: 'which gives the following output'... :)

Comment: you're still missing the point ... if you expect people to reproduce your output ... and to provide a workable solution ... you need to provide a complete set of input; there is no way anyone can take your sample input and reproduce your sample output

Comment: You're right, and I have updated the input accordingly! It's just my first time asking the question on Stack Overflow and also new to exploring with bash language. I will keep it in mind next time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Other great answers to the question you asked, I just wanted to suggest that instead of parsing/processing the `Gemfile.lock` yourself you can just use the `rails` executable:

```
rails -v | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Yes, indeed! Initially, I also thought of this solution but this won't work for the cases where the ruby version specified in the Gemfile.lock of a project is not installed in your system and where running ```rails -v```  results in an error like ``` 'Could not find the proper version of railties (6.1.4.1) in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems' ```

Comment: Good point, no problem.